# I have a link that I want to open in a new tab. As it is in a <div> I am unsure how to do this - I am new to php coding

Tags: html, hyperlink

This is the code I currently have, that opens the link in the same page.  I want to modify this to make it open in a new tab.

```
<div class="big-button" ">
    <a href="myurl"><input type="submit" value="Link name" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct me if wrong, I think you forgot to add the code.

Comment: @whyAto8 he added the code but the code was not highlighted

Comment: Not a php issue either.

Comment: A submit button inside a link?! Your problem has nothing to do with PHP or divs, you just need to learn HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
<div class="big-button" ">
    <a href="myurl" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="Link name" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `target="_blank"` in your anchor  `<a href="" target="_blank"></a>`

Comment: Did you see what he is nesting inside the `a`?

Comment: Also he is using `type="submit"` so inshort this question doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: Hint:`target='_blank'` is not validate W3C.

Comment: @Mr.Alien yup, you are absolutely rite. its not possible at all

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
<a href='URL' target='_blank'>xyz</a>
```

Give the your url as href attribute and give target attribute as _blank. It will open in new window

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="window.open('http://google.com')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
`target="_blank"` is not validate W3C.
Use this code in a tag:
`onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"`